# Woocommerce change order table view

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Good day!

I'm having a hard time how to change the order table in order confirmation email in woocommerce. See attached image thankyou!
[image: order confirmation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can edit most of the functionality and text, in the files inside this folder plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/ To avoid loosing all the changes during a woocommerce update copy those files with that same route path inside ur child theme or Example: yourchild-theme/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-footer.php
The question would be what is it you want to change in the order confirmation.